# VLOOKUP, or INDEX/MATCH?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

it might be an easy formula to populate table 2 with the information on table 1 but i am currently struggling to use multiple VLOOKUP functions. Has anyone please support me on this? the formula goes on cell B20 is basically checks if on that date(B19) a user(A20) has anything(A1:A13)..

[image: Final Look]

Comment: `=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/($B$1:$B$13=B$19)/($C$1:$C$13=$A20),$A$1:$A$13),"")` should do it.

Comment: That's great Rory, it works smoothly. Many Thanks :). May i ask why didn't you use VLOOKUP method just for curiosity?

Comment: You want values to the left of your criteria and you have two criteria. That makes VLOOKUP too complicated for my liking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INDEX /MATCH seems most logic to me for this:
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$13,MATCH(1,($C$1:$C$13=$A20)*($B$1:$B$13=B$19),0)),"")`
It indexes column A and shows value of the row where both criteria are true (1).

This returns the first match. If you want to show multiple matches then you should use a different approach, dependent on your Excel version.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: I am using Excel 2010, so i assume no XLOOKUP. What is the best way to pull all the entries for the same day for same person then?

Comment: That would require TEXTJOIN which is not available in excel 2010. You need to either 1) accept it's only showing 1 result, 2) iterate through all possible outcomes with INDEX/SMALL and concatenate them, which will slow things down immensely 3) rearrange the output data in a way we can show multiple types. Maybe a pivot table provides good insight in what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Another formula maybe simpler to Understand and manipulate:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX( $A$2:$A$14,MIN( IF(1*($B$2:$B$14=B$19)*($C$2:$C$14=$A20)=1,ROW($A$2:$A$14)-1,999))),"")
```

must be entered as array in first Cell (and after each edit), then copy-paste everywhere... (for array press ctrl+shift+enter instead of enter)

Also note that

1. in 06/11 Julie has 2 conditions and in both formulas only one is
   returned!
2. in 02/11 Toto is mistake in your example Raif
3. in Rory's formula changing 2 to 1 will give you the 1st encounter and thus get the 1st condition of Julie in 06/11 (1.)

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!